# Open CV Cmake g++ does not work on Rasbian jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie, opencv, make

I am compiling Open CV library on Raspbian jessie. I get below error .

```
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- broken
>     CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
>       The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/g++" is not able to compile a simple test
>       program.
```

I pointed it to g++-4.9 as well. Still I face the same issue. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try using `/usr/bin/g++` to compile a "Hello world" program. If it doesn't work, delete it and re-install. Check `type g++` in Terminal.

Comment: Thanks!I tried with g++ . But I do not see any change . It still pops up the same error. I actually do not need c++. All I am concentrating is on C. So is there any way I can skip this and build my OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found. I had two versions g++ and g++-4.9. I uninstalled both of them .Just installed g++4.9 and changed the path to /usr/bin/g++4.9. It solved the problem!